# update css and jquery map after use it

Tags: jquery, css, dictionary, responsive-design

i use css & jquery clickable map
[this is link of this plugin](http://winstonwolf.pl/clickable-maps/world-continents.html)

this map have many options and developer like me can change many thing like design and have many different sizes , but there is one problem and this map isnt responsive ,

so i deside when user resize window , if needed , i destroy map and rebuild again with size i want

but this work is not correctly right , so i searching to find any way that i can to update this map without destroy it ?

tnx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [Responsive Image Maps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps) plugin by Matt Stow. It recalculates area coordinatees to match the size of your image when the page first loads and also when the page resizes.

Comment: wonderfull thankyou just one other question  , how set map to image ?

Comment: i found it  , tnx again my friend